# Is hotfix rollup SDL Tridion 2011–1 means SDL Tridion 2011–SP1?

Tags: 2011

Just new to SDL Tridion need to know if my platform say that i have "Update Version - Hotfix rollup SDL Tridion 2011 - 1" does that mean it's "SDL Tridion 2011 SP1" ??

According to me, "Hotfix rollup SDL Tridion 2011 - 1" is not SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 but need expert advice. Please suggest.

Comment: Please see my earlier answer (and screenshot) here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/11453/71

Answer (score 9):

2011-1 means Tridion 2011 GA Hotfix Rollup 1.

2011SP1-1 means Tridion 2011 SP1 HOtfix Rollup 1. ... And so on.

Comment: While we're on the subject... GA stands for 'General Availability', and means the first released version of a product. So GA means "without any service packs".