# How to check which version i am having SDL Tridion 2011 or SDL Tridion 2011 SP1?

Tags: 2011, 2013-sp1, sdl-tridion

I might be silly asking this , but would be great if anyone can help.

Currently if i click on SDL Tridion icon(top right corner) in my CMS it says that I am on "Hot-fix roll-up SDL Tridion 2011 - 1" but quite not sure if this correct , i just want to make sure which version/hot-fix i am in 
SDL 2011 GA
SDL 2011 SP-1 etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Didn't the earlier answer provide you with the advise that you had wanted? http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7874/is-hotfix-rollup-sdl-tridion-2011-1-means-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question was about the difference between the versions. This is about how to be sure which one you have if you don't trust the version that Tridion reports.

Answer (score 5):

Open the Tridion App and choose 'About' from left hand-eclipse type menu item at the bottom, then you should be able to see similar screen shots below and know which version you have on your box.

**SDL Menu**

[image]

**SDL Tridion SP1 w/ HR1**

[image]

**SDL Tridion SP1**

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrew, I did the same it says "Update Version - Hotfix rollup SDL Tridion 2011 - 1 " does it means it is SDL2011- GA veriosn?

Comment: Also is there any way to check version on "Tridion Outbound" i am using?

Comment: Per your 1st question I believe Shiva is right with this post http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/7875/1439 - 2011 -1 equals GA release..

Answer (score 2):

You can also check in the database

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi I have tried this it says  "6.0.0.1 Content Manager Database SDL Tridion 2011 Database Manager Installation Aug  3 2011  2:09AM SDL Tridion 2011 Database Manager"